# Possible to install windows 8 apps without online account?

Tags: windows-8

Is it possible to install windows 8 apps without using online microsoft account to login to windows ? I had heard to be able to install windoes 8 apps, we need to use online account to login to windows but i want to use local account instead ?

Comment: Linking your user profile to a Microsoft Account is 100% optional.  Although that does not mean `Windows Store` does not require it.

Comment: You can operate without a MS account on the box; however, as Ramhound says - you need a MS account to use the Windows Store's central location.  However, you can install them from the web, just not the MS Store (I am assuming you're not on the 8RT editions).

Comment: yes I am not on windows 8RT

Answer (score 1):

Only Enterprise customers can deploy apps inside the cooperation without using the store with Windows 8 Enterprise. This is called [Sideloading](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2013/02/21/sideloading-windows-8-store-apps.aspx)